# JButton wont show components

Tags: java, swing, button

I want to make a simple Frame that would show a text field if I click on one button and would show a JLabel if I click on the other, but its not working and I'm not sure why?

I tried setting the variables to public but the result was the same, I also tried another commands in the button commands and it worked like showMessageDialog so I'm confused why it wont work

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class CheckBoxFrame extends JFrame
{
    private JTextField textField1;
    private JLabel label1;
    private JButton txt;
    private JButton label;
    public CheckBoxFrame()
    {

        super ("JCheckBox Test" );
        textField1= new JTextField ("Text Field 1", 20 );
        textField1.setFont ( new Font ("Serif", Font.PLAIN,14));
        add(textField1);
        textField1.setVisible(false);

        label1 = new JLabel("Label1", JLabel.CENTER);
        add(label1);
        label1.setVisible(false);

        txt = new JButton ("Text Field");
        ButtonHandler b1 = new ButtonHandler();
        txt.addActionListener(b1);
        add(txt);

        label = new JButton ("label ");
        add(label);

        setLayout( new FlowLayout() );
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(400,400);

    }


    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed   (ActionEvent a)
        {
            if (a.getSource() == txt)
            {
                label1.setVisible(false);
                textField1.setVisible(true);

            }

            if (a.getSource() == label)
            {
                label1.setVisible(true);
                textField1.setVisible(false);

            }
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Put `setLayout( new FlowLayout() );` before you add your components

Comment: @MadProgrammer i tried that too it won't show the text field unless I click the label first

Comment: Change `setSize(400,400);` to `pack()`

Answer (score 1):

Two things here
1. You have not added action listener for the label button.
2. Try calling repaint() of the JFrame after you set the visibility. Since you are using a separate action handler class you might have to pass the JFrame instance to the action handler through constructor or through a setter method.

It is always advisable to place the controls on a JPanel rather than placing it directly on a JFrame

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you add the `ButtonHandler` as an `ActionListener` to the `label`...

```
    label = new JButton("label ");
    add(label);
    label.addActionListener(b1);
```

Add `revalidate` to the end of the `ButtonHandler` (or where ever you modify the container) to force the layout manager to update the layout.  You may also need to use `repaint`

```
private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        if (a.getSource() == txt) {
            label1.setVisible(false);
            textField1.setVisible(true);

        }

        if (a.getSource() == label) {
            label1.setVisible(true);
            textField1.setVisible(false);
        }
        revalidate();
    }
}
```